# A question of bug of Numpy in Python. It turn a two size list to one size

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

I met a bug about numpy.

Here is my code:

```
huge_may_go =  np.array(pd.DataFrame(columns=range(2)))
```

```
def add_may_go(x,y):
    global huge_may_go
    counter = 0
    for i in range(-2,3):
        print(huge_may_go)
        cur_y = y + i 
        if cur_y < 0 or cur_y >= board_order:
            continue
        for j in range(-2,3):
            cur_x = x+j
            if (i == 0 and j == 0) or cur_x < 0 or cur_x >= board_order or ([cur_y,cur_x] == huge_may_go).all(1).any():
                continue
            if not public_grid[cur_y][cur_x]:
                huge_may_go = np.append(huge_may_go,[[cur_y,cur_x]],axis=0)
                counter += 1
    return counter
```

I am not familiar with numpy. I used to use "list" of python to make it run.

However, the speed of list of Python is not fast.

One of my friends tell me to try numpy.

However i met a searious problem

---

Thanks to @Corralien. I know that my code is not wrong.

I finnal know which code bring my erro:

it is the line next to it:

```
huge_may_go = np.delete(huge_may_go,[[gy,gx]])
```

however, it lead to another question. Why is it wrong?

before the sentence the huge may go is:

```
    [[7 7]
 [7 8]
 [7 9]
 [7 10]
 [7 11]
 [8 7]
 [8 8]
 [8 9]
 [8 10]
 [8 11]
 [9 7]
 [9 10]
 [9 11]
 [10 7]
 [10 8]
 [10 9]
 [10 10]
 [10 11]
 [11 7]
 [11 8]
 [11 9]
 [11 10]
 [11 11]]
```

however after it, it became:

[7 7 7 8 7 9 7 10 8 7 8 8 8 9 8 10 8 11 9 7 9 8 9 10 9 11 10 7 10 8 10 9 10 10 10 11 11 7 11 8 11 9 11 10 11 11]

I wanna know why

in this code, gx = 8  and gy = 9

---

Thanks to Corralien for another time

however, when i run it, the [9,8] is still in the array "huge_may_go"

or the way i delete is wrong?

thanks to everyone as well

---

I beg you to help me, Please.

In addition, if you have any idea of increase the speed of this code. Please tell me also.

The speed is the most important thing I care.

You may also tell me a way to impove the speed of the code instead. Thanks

I have search every where for this question. But my search engine tells me nothing!

In addition, if you have any idea of increase the speed of this code. Please tell me also.

The speed is the most important thing I care.

Comment: Can you show what the output should look like?

Comment: Yes i have already edit my question and you may look at the picture i post to look for more detail

Comment: What is the input for the `add_may_go`? Where are these numbers coming from?

Comment: it is  add_may_go(8,8)

Comment: What is the result you want?

Comment: x and y refers to number, in my input  x = 8 and y = 8

Comment: The true result i wany is a huge list contain the spot it scan and a counter tell me how many spot i have added

Comment: i really don't get it it would be great if you add `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` to the question it makes things easy to solve

Comment: I have edit my question already

Comment: What I don't understand is what are you trying to do with this function?

Comment: What this function is trying to do is search for the point that ai should go. I am makeing an ai based on a-b searching.

Comment: While i add a step, the "huge_may_go“ add steps and tells how many steps it add. Then i delet them from the end  when i delet the step i added

Comment: hi every one. Thank you very much, However it bring another question to me. If you would like to help me. please view the question again. I have edited it again. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

You have to reshape your array because `numpy.delete` flatten it:

```
huge_may_go = np.delete(huge_may_go,[[9,8]]).reshape(-1, 2)
```

---

Your code seems to work fine for me:

```
huge_may_go =  np.array(pd.DataFrame(columns=range(2)))
border_order = 19
public_grid = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]] * 24

def add_may_go(x,y):
    global huge_may_go
    counter = 0
    for i in range(-2,3):
        print(huge_may_go)
        cur_y = y + i 
        if cur_y < 0 or cur_y >= board_order:
            continue
        for j in range(-2,3):
            cur_x = x+j
            if (i == 0 and j == 0) or cur_x < 0 or cur_x >= board_order or ([cur_y,cur_x] == huge_may_go).all(1).any():
                continue
            if not public_grid[cur_y][cur_x]:
                huge_may_go = np.append(huge_may_go,[[cur_y,cur_x]],axis=0)
                counter += 1
    return counter

add_may_go(8, 8)
```

Output:

```
[]
[[6 6]
 [6 7]
 [6 8]
 [6 9]
 [6 10]]
[[6 6]
 [6 7]
 [6 8]
 [6 9]
 [6 10]
 [7 6]
 [7 7]
 [7 8]
 [7 9]
 [7 10]]
[[6 6]
 [6 7]
 [6 8]
 [6 9]
 [6 10]
 [7 6]
 [7 7]
 [7 8]
 [7 9]
 [7 10]
 [8 6]
 [8 7]
 [8 9]
 [8 10]]
[[6 6]
 [6 7]
 [6 8]
 [6 9]
 [6 10]
 [7 6]
 [7 7]
 [7 8]
 [7 9]
 [7 10]
 [8 6]
 [8 7]
 [8 9]
 [8 10]
 [9 6]
 [9 7]
 [9 8]
 [9 9]
 [9 10]]
24
```

Comment: ??? It shocked me!? There must have something wrong to other part of my program

Comment: Hi thank you very much. But this bring out another question. I've edit my question aready. If  you would like to, may you help me again?

Comment: Thank you very much. however it seems that it has not delete ([8,9]) from the "huge_may_go"

Comment: or i mean [9,8] as well

Comment: It deletes the values [6, 10] because there are the 8th and 9th position in the array.